# How can I objectively check my search engine ranking?

Tags: seo, google-search, rank-checkers

When I search on Google my companies website its rank gets distorted on my computer through previous searches, my location etc. I use private mode in my browser, but I think this is still not an accurate search.

I found some sites online that seem to check the ranking for me, but the ones I found all seem a little bit sketchy. So, how can I objectively check my search engine ranking for certain keywords?

Comment: I'm curious as to what happens with results if you tried searching for your web pages with other search engines such as bing.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood the question correctly then I think your referring to Google's caching that it thinks your logged in when your not and it favours results that you've clicked and searched before. Sadly this is a bit buggy on Google's behalf, lucky enough there's a work around or least what I do.

Install Google Chrome if you haven't and when you want to search for your site using targetted keywords then you should get Chrome to enter `incognito` mode. This can be done by holding:

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` then `N` you will then get a message ***You've gone incognito***.

```
Going incognito doesn't affect the behavior of other people, servers, or software. Be wary of:
Websites that collect or share information about you
Internet service providers or employers that track the pages you visit
Malicious software that tracks your keystrokes in exchange for free smileys
Surveillance by secret agents
People standing behind you
```

[Learn more](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) about incognito browsing.

Basically it disables Cookies meaning your not logged in, and no results are cached - you should get real results everytime by proceeding this way.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use firefox which has I think the equivalent "private browsing" mode to chromes "icognito" mode. It still seems to me that google recognizes me and ranks my own results higher. I will check with google chrome though. Also, I think it might realize that I am located closely to the address of my company.

Comment: Incognito mode does actually disable cookies, it just removes them at the end of the incognito session, so when you start a new incognito session you start off with no cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. Google tries to personalize based on geolocation, device, etc.

And even if you can turn off all those features, it won't help you, cause if your customers are from Germany with 80% mobile your unpersonalized ranking will not fit.

BUT there is a Search Console feature (you can connect it with Google Analytics), it shows you the average ranking between users. In my opinion thats way better to monitore your performance. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days, there used to be a ranking in Google, each website had  **page rank**. **Every** user used to see the same search results for a given search query and websites were ordered based in several (rather few compared with nowadays) factors, being the most important factor its page rank and the page rank of the websites that linked to its pages.

Today Google's page rank is just one of the thousands factors they use to rank a website and it's pages. Things had evolved to make a personalized user experience. **Users** will see different search results based in previous searches, language, location, and many more things, some of them can be *neutralized* with browser's **private mode**, but there is no general ranking anymore, there is no way to make sure that two different users will see the same results for the same query.

The closest tool to analyze webpages position for search queries objectively is to use the **Search Analytics Report** in **Search console**. Then you can see the search queries your site is receiving and their [positions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en) in SERP:

> Position - The average position of the top most result from your site.
>   So, for example, if your site has three results at positions 2, 4, and
>   6, the position is reported as 2. If a second query returned results
>   at positions 3, 5, and 9, your average position would be (2 + 3)/2 =
>   2.5. If a row of data has no impressions, the position will be shown as a dash (-), because the position doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Google has separate domain for you to track your ranking. Do select the domain and region where do you want to see your rank. for example for US select .com and location united states of america

[https://adwords.google.com/d/AdPreview/?_*u=1000000000&*_c=1000000000](https://adwords.google.com/d/AdPreview/?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000)

Comment: The link provided reports back that this is for "AdWords advertisers to test their ads."

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check website SERP on particular country, just go to a proxy site and search with TLD

example : if you want to search result from france go to google.fr on proxysite

in my research incognito,private window are not effective

Answer (score 0):

We use [Whitespark](https://whitespark.ca/) for tracking some high priority searches. We find it useful because our clients' sites are focused on local lead generation, so we can be fairly assured of where our searches will be/ought to be coming from.

The ad preview tool in AdWords may also be able to help in this regard, although admittedly it would be a truly laborious task even if you only have a few important services to promote. We usually use this only if a client has a specific concern (spoiler alert: they often do), so it's good for spot checking to make a point. ^_^